# query regarding joining of two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have 2 below tables

```
sql> select * from fraud_types ;

fraud_id       fraud_name
--------       ----------
       1       Fraud 1
       2       Fraud 2
       3       Fraud 3
       4       Fraud 4
       5       Fraud 5


sql> select * from alarms ;

fraud_id       dealer      count
--------       ------      -----
       1       Deal 1          5
       3       Deal 1          3
       5       Deal 1          4
       1       Deal 2          2
       2       Deal 2          6
       3       Deal 2          1
       4       Deal 2          7
       5       Deal 2          9
```

I want to join the two tables and get the output as

```
dealer      fraud_id        count
------      --------        -----
Deal 1             1            5
Deal 1             2            0
Deal 1             3            3
Deal 1             4            0
Deal 1             5            4
Deal 2             1            2
Deal 2             2            6
Deal 2             3            1
Deal 2             4            7
Deal 2             5            9
```

Basically I want to include the fields from fraud_types also and just display 0 in the output if it is not present in the alarms table. How can I achieve this ? Please help

Regards

Comment: I tried a right outer join between alarms and fraud_types. But it is not givin the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `cross join` to get all combinations and then a `left outer join`:

```
select d.dealer, f.fraud_id, coalesce(cnt, 0)
from (select distinct dealer from fraud_types) d cross join
     fraud_types f left outer join
     (select dealer, fraud_id, count(*) as cnt
      from fraud_types
      group by dealer, fraud_id
     ) df
     on df.dealer = d.dealer and df.fraud_id = f.fraud_id
order by d.dealer, f.fraud_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Partitioned outer join is very useful for cases like this:

```
select a.dealer, f.fraud_id, nvl(a.count,0) count
  from fraud_types f
  left outer join alarms a
      partition by (a.dealer)
      on a.fraud_id = f.fraud_id
 order by a.dealer, f.fraud_id
```

This does an outer join between alarms and fraud_types *for every value of dealer found in alarms.*

--

If the alarms table does not have (fraud,dealer) as key, then you can do a group by before the partition outer join:

```
select a.dealer, f.fraud_id, nvl(a.count,0) count
  from fraud_types f
  left outer join (
     select fraud_id
          , dealer
          , sum(count) count
       from alarms
      group by fraud_id, dealer
  ) a
      partition by (a.dealer)
      on a.fraud_id = f.fraud_id
 order by a.dealer, f.fraud_id
```

Comment: but how do I make it generic. I mean lets say if I do not know how many entries are there in fraud_types and how many entries are there in alarms per dealer, then I how to achieve this ?

Comment: Partitioned outer join *is* generic. The "with" clause is just a way to test the query on your data. The answer itself is just the last 6 lines - the query itself. I assumed from the data that (fraud_id,dealer) is a key in the alarms tables?

Comment: I added an edit to the answer showing how you can handle it if there are multiple rows in alarms table for each (fraud_id,dealer) combination.

Answer (score 0):

```
   select distinct f.fraud_id,dealer,
   (case when f.fraud_id=t.fraud_id then COUNT else 0 end) counts

   from 
   fraud_types f
   left  join
   alarms t
   partition by (dealer)
   on f.fraud_id=t.fraud_id 
   order by dealer
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the DISTINCT clause? I cannot think of a valid reason for including this?